# HTTPS is secure in Firefox but not secure in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, url, firefox, https

recently I encountered an issue regarding HTTPS. 
When I visit the HTTPS URL using Firefox, I can see a green padlock which showing it is a Secure connection.
However, when I visit the same HTTPS URL in Google Chrome, it is showing a Red connection NOT Secure sign.

Edit: Added Chrome Security Overview on the HTTPS
[image]

May I know why is this happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Firefox uses a different set of certs and optionally different connection settings from the system, unlike Chrome which matches the system. They may be why *something* is different. Can't possibly tell you *what* though from this information.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I have added with the Security Overview on the HTTPS from Chrome. Is this information enough?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate is no longer treated as valid by Chrome, following the deprecation of SHA-1. You can see in the picture that

> the certificate chain contains a certificate signed using SHA-1.

The certificate should be updated, which will probably happen soon anyway, as it is expiring in 2017 (according to the picture). More information here: https://security.googleblog.com/2016/11/sha-1-certificates-in-chrome.html

Quoting from the previous link:

> Starting with Chrome 54 we provide the EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors policy that allows certificates which chain to a locally installed trust anchor to be used after support has otherwise been removed from Chrome. Features which require a secure origin, such as geolocation, will continue to work, however pages will be displayed as “neutral, lacking security”. Without this policy set, SHA-1 certificates that chain to locally installed roots will not be trusted starting with Chrome 57, which will be released to the stable channel in March 2017. Note that even without the policy set, SHA-1 client certificates will still be presented to websites requesting client authentication. Since this policy is intended only to allow additional time to complete the migration away from SHA-1, it will eventually be removed in the first Chrome release after January 1st 2019.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that the certificate is using obsolete protocols. It is using an obsolete protocol which is TLS-1 and an obsolete cipher which is AES_256_CBC with HMAC SHA-1